# Extending Vendor Class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cart

I am using a cart system (\Gloudemans\Shoppingcart) but I want to override the default total() method:

```
namespace Gloudemans\Shoppingcart;
/**
     * Get the total price of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     * @return string
     */
    public function total($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        $total = $content->reduce(function ($total, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $total + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->priceTax);
        }, 0);

        return $this->numberFormat($total, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }
```

My extension:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Cart
{
    function __construct() {

    }

    public function total($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null) {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        $total = $content->reduce(function ($total, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $total + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->priceTax);
        }, 0);
        $currency = new Currency();
        $currency_id = $currency->where('code', session()->get('currency'))->first()->id;
        $rate = CurrencyRate::where('currency_id', $currency_id)->latest()->first()->rate;

        return $this->numberFormat($total*$rate, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }
}
```

However I am not sure how to access it, this is how I access the default method which works:

```
...
<span id="cart_total" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                               {{$symbol}} {{\Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::total()}}</span>
...
```

The facade above is:

```
namespace Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Cart extends Facade {
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'cart';
    }
}
```

Obviously the following doesn't work:

```
{{\App\Http\Controllers\CartController::total()}}
```

---

Here is a link to the cart system I am using:

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Comment: Are you sure a controller is the correct place to put that sort of logic in? Unless `CartController` is not an actual MVC controller.

Comment: Probably not, perhaps I need a folder called "helpers"?

Comment: I use a folder called "libraries" but depends what you prefer to call it. What I call libraries is probably not correct either

Comment: I add a pull request for the same issue with private methods that should be protected to allow overriding.

Comment: Any update here ? same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a dedicated class that overrides the default functionality.

```
class myCart extends Cart {

    public function total($decimals = null ....

}
```

now if you can create new instance of the myCart and use it to calculate total

```
var obj = new myCart();
obj->total();
```

If needed you can create the fascade for myCart class and use it.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting 'Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\CartController::getContent()'

Comment: Can you be more specific, it 'll help to answer

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following in a facade:

```
Facade::something();
```

is a shortcut for

```
app()->make(Facade::getFacadeAccessor())->something();
```

You therefore need to extend class returned by making a "cart" and override the `total` method in there.

E.g. assume :

```
class Cart { 
     //...
     public function total() {}
}

class MyCart extends Cart {
     //...
     //Your total:
     public function total() {}
}
```

**Note:** The first cart here is not the facade but the actual class that the facade returns.

Then you need to rebind it. To do this you need to make sure you have a service provider that runs after it's bound the first time and then:

```
 public function handle() {
        $this->app->bind("cart", function ($app) { return new MyCart(); });
 }
```

There shouldn't be any need to override the facade.

Comment: Do I need to replicate the constructor in the parent class? As I am getting errors relating to missing constructor params.

Comment: I am also getting errors with accessing private classes in the parent.

Comment: @imperium2335 If the parent has a constructor with parameters then you need to pass parameters when constructing the child as well, if you don't explicitly override the constructor then it will be inherited. Maybe doing `$app->make(MyCart::class)` will work instead of `new MyCart()`. Also in inheritance you can't access private members of the parent. The original authors must have had a reason for making those members private.